# Can Azure worker roles be deployed with git?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-worker-roles

Azure web sites can be conveniently deployed by pushing their git repository to a deployment URL.

Is the same thing possible with worker roles? I haven't found any information about this on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not natively available (i.e. built-in) to cloud services (Web/Worker roles).  However you do have full flexibility to implement your own solution which pulls contents from GitHub/wherever, and there are some projects that seek to provide this functionality, if that helps.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/git-azure

Comment: Forgot to mention that if you're interested, you can run "WorkerRole" like background tasks using Azure WebJobs, which are built on Azure WebSites.http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/